# How to escape command output (oneliner) in zsh

Tags: zsh

I have this wonderful music library app: beets.

When I run `beet ls somequery -f`, I get a newline-separated list of my music files' paths. Unfortunately, the paths contain unescaped spaces and I can't feed mplayer like this:

```
mplayer `beet ls smooth`
```

This doesn't work either:

```
mplayer $((q)beet ls smooth)
```

Could anyone provide a compact solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mplayer ${(f)"$(beet ls smooth)"}`

Comment: Marked this one because xargs cause problems with mplayer (one cannot control it). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `xargs`:

```
beet ls smooth | xargs mplayer
```

This will protect the filenames against spaces, but not newlines. (I'm assuming they don't contain newlines, as the program `beet` produces a newline-separated list.)

Comment: I needed to add a delimiter option: -d '\n' :)

Comment: Ah, sorry for forgetting that. :) (In fact, I use `-0` wherever possible.)